# Get value using JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I am trying to get a value of each name displayed in a table. I want to have a button beside each name as a 'favourite' button. Each name displayed has a unique number ID, and i was wondering how am i able to get this?

at the moment, when i click the fav button all that appears is:
`.$dbRow[`

Can someone help?

```
$i = 0;
while($i < $counter) {
  echo '<tr>';
  if(isset($arr['nameB'][$i])) {
    echo ''.$arr['nameB'][$i].'value=".$arr["nameB"].">Add</button></td>';
  }else{

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).prop('id');  
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Is your PHP executing?

Comment: yes it is working fine.

Comment: Ah - you've a bad concatenation and your PHP variable is not being interpoleted. `id="' . $dbRow["nameID"] . '"`

Answer (score 3):

Your concatenation is off in the following line:

```
echo '<td>'.$arr['BoysName'][$i].'<button class="favourites" id=".$dbRow["nameID"]. value=".$arr["BoysName"].">Favourite</button></td>'
```

It should be

```
echo '<td>'. $arr['BoysName'][$i] . '<button class="favourites" id="' . $dbRow["nameID"] . '" value="' . $arr["BoysName"] . '">Favourite</button></td>'
```

Comment: [Works perfectly for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/a21zgutz/) Check to make sure your HTML is well formed.

Comment: @Becca: Double check the quotes (singles and doubles) and make sure the line ends with a `;` The above answer is correct.